# You have requested document class X but the document class provides Y warning

Tags: templates, document-classes, warnings

I got this warning:

```
You have requested document class `Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF',
           but the document class provides `PhDThesisPSnPDF'.
```

How can I silence it? It looks like a multiline warning and I don't know how to copy it in `\WarningFilter` command. Here is my attempt that failed:

```
 \WarningFilter{latex}{ `Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF',but the document class provides `PhDThesisPSnPDF'}
```

Comment: It is warning you about an error in your document so the best way is to fix the error. use `\documentclass{PhDThesisPSnPDF}` not `\documentclass{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}`

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem, I also copied the class file beside the main tex file

Comment: https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/issues/112

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This stems from the fact that you have `PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls` inside a `Classes` subfolder. So, the way you normally include it is to use

```
\documentclass[..]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
```

right? Well, there should be similarity between what is supplied within `\documentclass`'s mandatory argument - the class - and what is written inside the mandatory argument of `\ProvidesClass` inside `PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls`. If they don't match, LaTeX throws the warning you see.

You can't use the [`silence` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence) for this unless you load it *before* calling `\documentclass`. Moreover, you don't have to supply the *full* warning message in order to filter it; just a matching start would do.

How can you rectify this warning? One of a number of ways:

1. Edit the `PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls` file inside the `Classes` subfolder and change

   ```
   \ProvidesClass{PhDThesisPSnPDF}
   ```

   to

   ```
   \ProvidesClass{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
   ```

   and then directly use

   ```
   \documentclass[..]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
   ```

   inside your document.
2. Move `PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls` from the `Classes` folder to where you have your `.tex` source.
3. Move `PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls` to your local TeXMF folder and rerun `texhash` (making it available for all documents).

Comment: While compartmentalisation might be important, consider option 2.

Comment: I copied the cls file to the same path ot tex file and changed \documentclass{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF} to \documentclass{PhDThesisPSnPDF} that solved the problem. I suppose your answer solve it as well so I accept it.

Comment: can you please edit the title of question so it can be more useful for others?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry, I reconfigured the layout. (2) was already in use.

Comment: https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/issues/112

Comment: (4) Ignore the warning.

Answer (score 7):

The following is directly from [the templates README file](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/#w1-i-get-the-latex-warning-you-have-requested-document-class-classesphdthesispsnpdf-but-the-document-class-provides-phdthesispsnpdf-should-i-be-concerned):

> ## Troubleshooting warnings
>
> **W1: I get the LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF`, but the document class provides `PhDThesisPSnPDF`, should I be concerned?**
>
> No! Do nothing, or if you don't want any warning messages change the line near the top of the class file to `\ProvidesClass{Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF}` if you're not going to install the class file in a more standard location. You can install it in a standard location like `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/` and run texhash to reconfigure.

Please see also [issue 112](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/issues/112)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and for me I do not have the possibility of moving the .cls file because it has some dependencies on the files that live within that directory (imported as a Git submodule). And my custom class needs to be useable also within its own directory. My solution was to do this, at the beginning of the .cls file:

```
    \IfFileExists{./<your class name>.cls}{
        \ProvidesClass{<your class name>}[<your class description>]
    }{
        \ProvidesClass{./<subdirectory>/<your class name>}[<your class description>]
    }
```

And it removed the warning when compiling both inside the .cls subdirectory and in the top directory.