# Suppress Warning "You have requested package `"blablabla/mypackage"', but the package provides `mypackage'."

Tags: packages, warnings

In a main tex file, I load my style file `mypackage.sty` by

```
\usepackage{blablabla/mypackage}
```

This absolute reference is inevitable for my purpose (impossible to change the location of the style file)

The code runs well, but it always raises a warning:

```
"You have requested package "blablabla/mypackage", but the package provides mypackage."
```

I can understand why it raises a warning, but How can I suppress this warning?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{You have requested package}` after loading your `\documentclass` and it should suppress any such warnings.

Comment: The root of your problem is the location of your package(s). Why do you store them in a separate folder? Why aren't they part of the (La)TeX distribution?

Comment: Related: [You have requested document class X but the document class provides Y warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354098/5764)

Comment: the absolute reference isn't inevitable you could/should for example use `TEXINPUTS=blablabla: pdflatex yourfile`  then `\usepackage{mypackage}`

Comment: \Werner It then shows a new warning "\sl@wwarningCount=\count92\sl@WarningNUmber=......" (I am using texmaker)

Comment: \Werner I store them in a dropbox folder to share it with others

Comment: \David Carlisle Thanks!

Comment: Also note that use `@` not ``\`` to ping other people. — Besides changing that, it's also possible to just symlink the file to the directory with the TeX file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I can just use the following code:

```
\def\input@path{{blablabla/}}
\usepackage{mypackage}
```

Comment: Surrounding `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands seem compulsory.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and solved it by writing `\ProvidesPackage{blablabla/mypackage}` in the `.sty` file like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{blablabla/mypackage}
```